# Struct | assign struct objects | Segmentation Fault Error

Tags: c, linux, pointers, struct

I define a `struct` type as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    int obs_flag;
    double obs_timestamp;
    int event_mask;
    char *event_name;
    char *filedir;
} structdata;
```

where I have a pointer named `obs_data`:

```
structdata *obs_data;
```

then I want to assign each object of the `obs_data` as follows:

```
int observer_flag = 1;
double ctime = 2309212380.323100;
struct inotify_event* event = (struct inotify_event*)(buffer + bytesProcessed);

obs_data->obs_flag = observer_flag;
obs_data->obs_timestamp = ctime;
obs_data->event_mask = event->mask;
obs_data->event_name = event->name;
obs_data->filedir = "./myDir/";
```

in the above, `event` is a struct from the `inotify` that captures the events associated with changes to a file or directory in Linux.

when I run the above chunk of code in my program I encounter the `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

I am not a pro working with stucts and pointers. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `double ctime = 2309212380.323100` a semicolon is missing here. Also what is `buffer`? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How did you initialize the pointer `obs_data` itself, not what is pointed at by that?

Comment: `where I instantiate and "observer data" no you are not. You still need to allocate memory for it. Theres no "instantiation" in C.

Comment: I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `obs_data` is just a pointer!! It's not an instance of `structdata`. If you want it to be a pointer, you need to `malloc` memory to hold the struct.

So before using `obs_data` you need code like:

```
obs_data = malloc(sizeof *obs_data);  // Allocate memory for 1 instance of structdata
if (obs_data == NULL)
{
    // allocation failed
    exit(1);
}
// Now you can assign values like
obs_data->obs_flag = observer_flag;
...
...
```

and once you are done using it, remember to free the memory like

```
free(obs_data);
```